# AngularJS -> selecting DOM elements rendered by AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have implemented a directive which generates html table's columns and rows, also it assigns an id for a table using {{}}. I need to run some jQuery function to add additional behavior to the table.

I'm having a trouble selecting table from DOM. When I'm trying to select it, it seems that table doesn't exist at that particular moment, I tried using jQuery's $(document).ready(), but it didn't work out. The only solution that works is using a timeout, but it is kind of dirty thing to do. Is there any elegant way of solving this issue?

EDIT:

I added an example code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/c4NIzFy8xVyPsDLRYEeX?p=preview).

`$('#' + scope.gridId + ' tr th').resizable({
    handles: 'e'
 });`

The table below has got resizable columns and I'm trying to achieve the same result with generated table.

Comment: `$(document).ready` and pure jQuery/javascript doesn't behave well with angular. You will need to put all the logic in a directive `link` function. Mind showing some code, or an example?

Comment: The dirty thing is to use jQuery, if you are outside of angular context you need a timeout (preferably `$timeout`) to wait for angular to compute the HTML before you can manipulate it.

Comment: Some code would help.  It seems you are using ng-repeat and a directive.  If so, there are better ways than using the $timeout hack.  99 times out of 100 if you are using $timeout to fix an issue in a directive related to the DOM not being in a state you expect, it's because you haven't truly embraced doing things "the Angular way".